# Black Images when transforming HTML to Jpeg

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

I need to add a feature on my app that allows users to save, as an image, in their Photo Documents on the device, a portion of the App.

I'm using Nuxt.js and the content is just inside a Dialog, simple like this:

```
<v-card ref="print" outlined class="certificate">
  <v-img :src="photo.url"></v-img>
  <v-card-text>
    {{ photo.title }}
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

The image src is on external storage, not in my assets, ofc...

The code to generate the file to be saved is the following:

```
      const el = this.$refs.print
      const options = {
        type: 'dataURL',
        useCors: true,
        scale: 2,
        logging: false,
      }
      try {
        const canvas = await this.$html2canvas(el, options)
        await Filesystem.writeFile({
          path: `certificate-${this.photo.id}.jpeg`,
          data: canvas,
          directory: Directory.Documents,
        })
      } catch (error) {
        // ...
      }
```

It works, it gets the right portion of HTML and saves a Jpeg to my Documents, unfortunately, the images within are always total black...

Why???
How can I fix this?

Comment: You use ionic and capacitor as tags, yet the post describes nothing about it. Is this on iOS, Android or desktop in a browser?

Comment: It is a Capacitor application built with Nuxt, as you can see I use `Filesystem.writeFile()`

Comment: have you tried console.logging the `el`. dialog content is lazy loaded, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: it is lazy loaded, but the whole elements are not undefined in all logs I added.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide any `encoding` options to `Filesystem.writeFile()` and is therefore saved as base64 encoded per default. The HTML canvas-element is not base64 encoded.

Comment: Thanks, I used another library `html-to-image`, used the `toPng` method, used the base64 generated and I still cannot see the image, it is still black...